# How to obtain the details of a gerrit change which is directly submitted / merged on the server

Tags: git, ssh, gerrit

I'm trying to obtain the details of a change (branch, server url, author, committer etc) with the SHA of the commit using a gerrit query. The change was directly submitted to the server, which means there were no reviews done on the change.

I used the following command which returned nothing.

```
ssh -p <PORT> <Server> gerrit query --current-patch-set <SHA>

type: stats
rowCount: 0
runTimeMilliseconds: 4
moreChanges: false
```

Can anyone please help me out with an alternative command that I can use to obtain this data.

Comment: It seems impossible. There was no Change created for such commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't search for a SHA commit using the UI search field, the ssh gerrit command or the REST API if the commit was submitted directly to branch (refs/heads/branch) bypassing Gerrit.

You can clone the repository (if you know what is the specific repository) and find some info about the commit executing "git show SHA" or "git log SHA", for example.